# Fourier coefficients sum converges

Tags: fourier-analysis

Let $f:[−\pi, \pi] \to \mathbb R$ be continuous with $f(−\pi) =  f(\pi)$ extend $f$ to $\mathbb R$
by periodicity conditions.  Assume that for some $\alpha > \frac{1}{2}$ we have

$$\displaystyle\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}\big|\frac{f(x+h) - f(x)}{h^\alpha}\big|^2 < \infty.$$
Show that $\displaystyle\sum_{n = -\infty}^{\infty} |\hat f(n)| < \infty$

Answer (score 1):

Define $ g_h(x)= f(x+h) -f(x), ~ x \in [-\pi, \pi] $ and $ h \in \mathbb R $. Observe that
$$
\hat g_h(n) = (e^{inh}-1)\hat f(n), ~~~h \in \mathbb R ~~\mbox{and}~~|\hat g_h(n)|= 2|\sin \dfrac{nh}{2}||\hat f(n)|
$$
By hypothesis, there exists $ M\geq 0$ such that

$$
 \displaystyle\int_{-\pi}^{\pi} |g_h(x)|^2 \,dx = M h^{2 \alpha}.
$$
Now Parseval's identity yields
$$
 2 \pi \displaystyle\sum_{-\infty}^{\infty} |\hat g_h(n)|^2 =  M h^{2 \alpha}.
$$
Then 
$$
2 \pi \displaystyle\sum_{-\infty}^{\infty} 4|\sin \dfrac{nh}{2}|^2|\hat f(n)|^2 =  M h^{2 \alpha}.
$$
Choose $ h= \dfrac{\pi}{2^k} $ for arbitrary but fix $ k \in \mathbb N $ and
$ 2^{k-1} \leq |n| < 2^k $ which implies $ \dfrac{\pi}{4} \leq |n|\dfrac{h}{2} < \dfrac{\pi}{2}$. Then $ |\sin (\dfrac{|n|h}{2})|^2 = |\sin (\dfrac{nh}{2})|^2 \geq \dfrac{1}{2}$ and 
[
 $\displaystyle\sum_{-\infty}^{\infty}  |\hat f(n)|^2 \leq  \dfrac{M}{4\pi} (\dfrac{\pi}{2^k})^{2 \alpha}$.
]
By  Cauchy Schwarz inequality,
\begin{align*}
\displaystyle\sum_{2^{k-1} \leq |n| < 2^k} |\hat f(n)| &\leq  (\displaystyle\sum_{2^{k-1} \leq |n| < 2^k} 1^2)^\frac{1}{2} 
(\displaystyle\sum_{2^{k-1} \leq |n| < 2^k} |\hat f(n)|^2)^\frac{1}{2} \\
& \leq (2^k - 2^{k-1} )^\frac{1}{2}  \big[\dfrac{M}{4\pi} (\dfrac{\pi}{2^k})^{2 \alpha}\big]^\frac{1}{2}\\
&= \dfrac{\sqrt{M}\pi^{\alpha-\frac{1}{2}}}{2^\frac{3}{2}}\dfrac{1}{2^{(\alpha-\frac{1}{2})k}}
\end{align*} 
By taking summation over $ k \in \mathbb N $ it follows that (in addition use the fact that $ |\hat f(0)|^2 < \infty \Rightarrow |\hat f(0)| < \infty$),
 $$ \displaystyle\sum_{n = -\infty}^{\infty} |\hat f(n)| < \infty$$